# Laravel passport with Cartalyst Sentinel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-passport, cartalyst-sentinel

I am using laravel passport and sentinel for developing API. I want to use it with VUE js. But I am getting a problem in `oauth/token`.

When I hit the URL I get an error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAuthPassword()

My User Model code is

```
namespace App;

use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends EloquentUser
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'password',
        'name',
        'permissions',
        'photo_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function findForPassport($username) {
        return $this->where('email', $username)->first();
    }


    public function photo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }
}
```

If I use `Class User extends Authenticatable` then it works and get

```
status: 200, statusText: "OK"
```

, But if I use `EloquentUser` then I get error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:: getAuthPassword()

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the error.

Call to **undefined method** Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAuthPassword()

So I just put Authenticatable trait as `Use Authenticatable;` and import the class in namespace 
 `use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;`

Comment: can you share a code example please?

Comment: https://github.com/kapilpaul/laravel-quickstart this repo might help you. Note: this is an old repo

Comment: i know it is old. is there any solution? else this code.